# Is there a drag-and-drop form designer that could be easily customized for any widget framework?

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, widget, windows-forms-designer

As far as I know, right now there is no free (not even cheap) visual designer for making AS3 apps. It's not like it is not possible to create one - just like I can write the GUI definition code in FlashDevelop we could have this hypothetical tool generate it based on drag and drop actions, but at present nobody has built one yet.

So suppose we wanted to build such a tool for AS3 widgets or for some others such buttons and text boxes widget framework. Is there a generic form builder tool that we could customize for this purpose? Or would basically the only (barely) customizable thing on the table be the forms designer component from .net framework? It could hypothetically be beaten into representing the AS3 etc framework widgets as user defined controls with us running a separate tool to automatically convert the C# form definition code into the target framework language, e.g. into runnable AS3 apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought about this myself as I am in the process ( and have been for a while ) of developing my own cross-platform flash IDE. I think that the whole thing just appears to be much more complex than it is. If you were to simply create a UI designer in Adobe AIR you could package this for cross-platform distro and embed it in a larger app or just use it standalone. This way you don't have to re-create the components for flash (ui objects) you can just embed those assets in your form designer. I've also thought about class integration too, and that should be pretty simple you'd just need to read/write the constructor of display-object classes added to the "stage" and then transform the object in the form designer at runtime. Also for timeline creation the way the Flash IDE does this (as far as actionscript goes) is it simply attaches chunks of code you write on frames using the undocumented addFrameScript method, so frame-based code snippets would be easy to implement as well.

Anyway there is one such project that exists but its supposed to output MXML.

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&offeringid=10299&marketplaceid=1

Comment: are you saying that the visual designer should be written itself as AS3 app and it should generate compilable AS3 code based on the locations, sizes and other properties of widgets I create on it? That makes good sense to me (although not sure how easy it is to make a user-friendly designer like WinForms one, that's why I suggested using an off-the-shelf thingie). Or do you mean something more elaborate?

Comment: I'm saying to develop the visual designer to handle both portions. So it will generate necessary code to apply the visual transformations being applied in the design view (using pure AS3) and also read existing code to update the design view, much like the design view in the Flash CS IDE and the Flash Builder IDE does. I'm basically saying to do what the AIR app in the link above does, just a little more enhanced.